# Hybrid mobile application crash while adding cordova.js

Tags: javascript, android, html, jquery-mobile, cordova

I am developing a hybrid mobile application using Phonegap and jQuery mobile. My application works fine without the addition of cordova.js but when I add the cordova.js the application shows some error and crashes.

I want to add the Phonegap back button event inside my code but it also not working, I hope the cordova.js problem might be the issue. I am using Cordova 2.4.0.

Here is my logcat and my code:

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.css">

        <script src="js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
       <script type="text/javascript" src="js/cordova.js"></script>

 <script type="text/javascript">

 function onLoad() {
     document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
 }

  function onDeviceReady() {

        document.addEventListener("backbutton", backKeyDown, true);
        alert("Phonegap ready!");

        console.log("PhoneGap is ready");
    }

    function backKeyDown() {
         alert("bak event here ready!");
        navigator.app.exitApp(); // To exit the app!
    }

  </script>


</head>
<body onload="onLoad()">
<div data-role="page">

<!-- header -->

<div data-role="header" style="background-color: #3399FF"class="ui-header-fixed" data-theme="b"><h1><font color="#ffffff">Mobile Bank</font></h1></div>

<div data-role="main" style="background-color: #DCDCDC">

<div align="center">
<img src="img/display_image2.jpg" style="width:330px;height:350px">
</div>

<ul data-role="listview" data-divider-theme="b" data-inset="true" >
<li>
<fieldset class="ui-field-contain" data-inline="true" data-inset="true">
<input type="password" data-inline="true" data-mini="true" placeholder="Mpin here" data-theme="b" id="mpin" >
<a href="" data-role="button" data-mini="false" rel="external" data-theme="a" id="log_btn" onclick="return Validate()">Login</a>

</fieldset>
<div align="right">
<a href="forget_pin_page.html"  data-role="button" data-mini="true" data-inline="true" rel="external" data-theme="b" >Forgot Mpin?</a>
</div>
</li>
</ul>

<div data-role="ui-field-contain" align="center">   
<table><tr><td width="50%" align="center">



        <div data-role="popup" id="logout">
                           <div data-role="main">
                                  <h2 align="center">Exit Application</h2>
                                  <p>&nbsp;Are you sure want to Exit?&nbsp;</p>
                                  <div align="center">
                                         <a href="#" data-role="button" data-theme="b" rel="external"
                                                data-inline="true">Yes</a> <a href="#" data-role="button"
                                                data-theme="b" data-rel="back" data-inline="true">No</a>
                                  </div>
                           </div>
                     </div>
</div>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Logcat

```
05-23 01:16:30.510: E/AndroidRuntime(1272): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-23 01:16:30.510: E/AndroidRuntime(1272): Process: com.nest.mobilebanking, PID: 1272
05-23 01:16:30.510: E/AndroidRuntime(1272): java.lang.RuntimeException: Error receiving broadcast Intent { act=android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE flg=0x4000010 (has extras) } in org.apache.cordova.NetworkManager$1@b3d99538
05-23 01:16:30.510: E/AndroidRuntime(1272):     at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args.run(LoadedApk.java:778)
05-23 01:16:30.510: E/AndroidRuntime(1272):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
05-23 01:16:30.510: E/AndroidRuntime(1272):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
05-23 01:16:30.510: E/AndroidRuntime(1272):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
05-23 01:16:30.510: E/AndroidRuntime(1272):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
05-23 01:16:30.510: E/AndroidRuntime(1272):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-23 01:16:30.510: E/AndroidRuntime(1272):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
05-23 01:16:30.510: E/AndroidRuntime(1272):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
05-23 01:16:30.510: E/AndroidRuntime(1272):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
05-23 01:16:30.510: E/AndroidRuntime(1272):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-23 01:16:30.510: E/AndroidRuntime(1272): Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: ConnectivityService: Neither user 10052 nor current process has android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE.
05-23 01:16:30.510: E/AndroidRuntime(1272):     at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1465)
05-23 01:16:30.510: E/AndroidRuntime(1272):     at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1419)
```

Answer (score 2):

Do you have 'android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE' in your AndroidManifest file? Logcat says you do not have it, so add it.

Comment: Oops thanks buddy it works fine now , I have added that permission and later I have commented those because of some proxy error , now its ok ., And one more information I have got is I must use android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE' to handle cordova.js  Have a good day  :)

Comment: happy to help you little, nice weekend!